# Access MySQL remotely with terminal and PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, remote

First I must say that it's the first time I'm doing this kind of stuff, I'm a bit confused. I've uploaded a MySQL database to a website I bought few hours ago which I can access through PHPMyAdmin. I'd like to connect remotely to this database from a Linux PC, through terminal using mysql command line, something like `mysql -u "user" -p "password" -h "hostname"`.

If I try this I get an error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user_xxx'@'xxx.xx.xxx.xx'
> (using password: YES)

Searching on the internet I found that PHPMyAdmin blocks the possibility to access the database remotely, and it seems I can't manage to change this in the website control panel.

Is there a way to solve this?